# how to stop OS X Core Data Spotlight help tags showing external record file path?

Tags: macos, core-data, spotlight

I am developing a non-document-based core data app for OS X 10.6. It is based on the template generated by XCode 3.2.4 when "Create document-based application" is **not** checked and "Use Core Data for Storage" and "Include Spotlight Importer" **are** checked.

My spotlight importer sets kMDItemDisplayName to a summary of the row of the main database table. No other kMDItem attributes are set. No metadata is imported from the persistent store, only from the external record files.

Everything works fine with one exception:

When I hover my mouse over a Spotlight result, the yellow help tag shows the path to the external records file for the corresponding database record. That looks like gibberish to the average user, i.e. 
/Users/username/Library/Caches/Metadata/CoreData/appname/uuid/entity/x/y.

Is there any way to stop that from happening? Ideally, I would like the help tag to refer to my application's name.

I tried setting several of the other kMDItem attributes, but they don't appear to change the displayed help tag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `<displayattrs>` element of your importer's `schema.xml` file? If that doesn't work, please file a [bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: The code generated by XCode 3.2.4 for a Cocoa Core Data application with Spotlight importer project doesn't include a schema.xml file. That file only is generated in a Spotlight plugin project.

I tried adding a schema.xml file to my importer's bundle, and it seems to have no effect. For example, I specify <displayattrs>kMDItemTextContent</displayattrs>, but the Spotlight search result still displays kMDItemDisplayName (with the unwanted path).

Comment: Well, there may very well be a bug… But `kMDItemTextContent` is not an attribute that can be fetched back from Spotlight, so I would not expect that one to work in any case. Please do report this to Apple officially using the bugreport link provided above.

Comment: I filed a bug report. I think the root cause of the problem is the the CoreData-generated External Record File is imported into Spotlight as a "Document", and Spotlight displays the file path in the Help Tag for all documents. I'm wondering if there is a way to import the metadata as on object type other than Document? I don't see any obvious kMDItem tags that could do that.